# Android WebView downloadlistener not fired when trying to download dynamic files in JSF

Tags: android, jsf, webview, download

I'm trying to fire a DownloadListener event on Android's WebView when I click in a download button in a JSF page, those downloads links are generated dynamically.
It works just fine in Google Chrome, but it doesn't work at WebView and I couldn't figure it out.

I just need this event to be fired when the button is clicked.
Can you help me?

Download:

```
public void download(Download obj) throws IOException {
    byte[] download = .... // obj byte[] loaded here
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context
            .getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(download.length));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"download\"");
    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(download),
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(),
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
        output.close();
    }
    context.responseComplete();
}
```

Datatable download:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{downloadBean.downloads}" var="obj"
                                 emptyMessage="#{erros.sem_registros}">
                        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.acoes}" styleClass="width50">
                            <h:form>
                                <h:commandLink value="#{msgs.download}" action="#{downloadBean.download(obj)}" />
                            </h:form>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

WebView event:

```
viewer.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download ativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String retorno = new DownloadUtil().getNew(url);
                if (retorno != null) {
                    findBT();
                    openBT();
                    sendData(retorno);
                    closeBT();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Não foi possível receber o arquivo do servidor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conexão mal sucedida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```